# Mysql UPDATE com JOIN e WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

Minhas tabelas

```
EMPREGADO   Cod_Emp, Nome_Emp
COMPANHIA   Cod_Comp, Nome_Comp
TRABALHA    Cod_Emp, Cod_Comp, Salário, Cod_Emp_Supervisor
```

Quero dar um aumento de 10% a todos os supervisores da empresa 'teste'.

```
UPDATE trabalha 
INNER JOIN companhia ON trabalha.Cod_Comp = companhia.Cod_Comp AND companhia.Nome_comp = 'teste'
SET salario = salario + (salario*0.10)
WHERE Cod_Emp IN (SELECT Cod_Emp_Supervisor FROM trabalha)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE
    TRABALHA T
INNER JOIN
    COMPANHIA C ON 
    (
        C.Cod_Comp = T.Cod_Comp
        AND
        C.Nome_comp = 'Teste'
        AND
        T.Cod_Emp = T.Cod_Emp_Supervisor
    )
SET
    T.Salario = T.Salario + (T.Salario * 0.10)
```

Pelo que entendi a coluna Cod_Emp_Supervisor na tabela TRABALHA indica quem é o supervisor de cada funcionário dentro da COMPANHIA.

Como não conheço a base ou o sistema que da carga na mesma. Imagino que o campo Cod_Emp_Supervisor será preenchido com o próprio código do supervisor. Ou caso não seja preenchido fique nulo, basta substituir a cláusula **T.Cod_Emp = T.Cod_Emp_Supervisor** para  **T.Cod_Emp_Supervisor IS NULL**.

Comment: Fiz desse jeito, mas não é bem o que eu queria. Eu estava tentando verificar com o *WHERE* os **Cod_Emp** com os **Cod_Emp_Supervisor**, assim eu saberia que aquele funcionário é um supervisor. E depois verificar as a empresa que ele trabalha com o *JOIN*.

Comment: @vdschuck Na tabela TRABALHA o empregado do tipo supervisor o campo Cod_Emp_Supervisor fica nulo ou com o mesmo código do campo Cod_Emp?

Comment: Por isso coloquei no JOIN a cláusula _T.Cod_Emp = T.Cod_Emp_Supervisor_ para obter somente os supervisores.